# Div Overlapping each other - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am to position my Social Icons at the bottom of the Screen and position my Image Gallery in the middle of the screen however, the social Icons move to the middle of the screen and the Image gallery seems to be overlapping my Social Icons and I cannot position it to stay at the bottom of the screen

Every time I add something new to the page, it tends to affect the social icon

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Images</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/ace.png"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        <link href="example/imageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
        <link href="example/jphotogrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
        <!--[if IE]>
            <link href="jphotogrid.ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <![endif]--> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="example/jphotogrid.js"></script>
        <script src="example/jflickrfeed.js"></script>
        <script src="example/setup.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="header">
        </div>                    
        <span class="menu-Trigger" align="center" >&#9776; Menu</span>
        <div class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>VIDEOS</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="Images.html">IMAGES</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>EVENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">ENQUIRIES</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <ul id="pg">
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3647/3435384001_9ed9864bb4.jpg" alt="DSC_0660">
                    <p>DSC_0660</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3311/3436188742_caaa28c689.jpg" alt="DSC_0698">
                    <p>DSC_0698</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3371/3436188466_418a0d8a06.jpg" alt="DSC_0668">
                    <p>DSC_0668</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3397/3436188128_5e503cefcd.jpg" alt="DSC_0704">
                    <p>DSC_0704</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3300/3436187796_4d228a5bde.jpg" alt="DSC_0699">
                    <p>DSC_0699</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3386/3435382439_68b5e3742b.jpg" alt="DSC_0602">
                    <p>DSC_0602</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3657/3436187288_e84058f54b.jpg" alt="DSC_0603">
                    <p>DSC_0603</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3405/3436187010_c731dea9a3.jpg" alt="DSC_0604">
                    <p>DSC_0604</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3403/3435381659_ea615ecf14.jpg" alt="DSC_0607">
                    <p>DSC_0607</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3570/3436186474_4e35487600.jpg" alt="DSC_0619">
                    <p>DSC_0619</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3339/3434101571_30f6f2bffd.jpg" alt="DSC_0620">
                    <p>DSC_0620</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3134/3434099407_32da82e761.jpg" alt="DSC_0590">
                    <p>DSC_0590</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3538/3434096369_e2de95b252.jpg" alt="DSC_0562">
                    <p>DSC_0562</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3348/3434093487_f5a5b8fdb3.jpg" alt="DSC_0544">
                    <p>DSC_0544</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3652/3434091639_dccdc6342a.jpg" alt="DSC_0541">
                    <p>DSC_0541</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3537/3434089449_cde6162fa7.jpg" alt="DSC_0532">
                    <p>DSC_0532</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3385/3434895530_4bf2857b49.jpg" alt="DSC_0531">
                    <p>DSC_0531</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3411/3434069355_7df0d65490.jpg" alt="Dog dogs">
                    <p>dogs</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3349/3434870890_3b51171084.jpg" alt="DSC_0693">
                    <p>DSC_0693</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3544/3434061033_ba1be12cce.jpg" alt="DSC_0691">
                    <p>DSC_0691</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <section>
            <div id="middle">
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="sI">
            <div class="icons">
                <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.youtube.com" title="Subscribe on YouTube" alt="Arshdeep on YouTube"><img src="images/social/youtube.png"/></a>
        <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.instagram.com/ArshSoni" title="Subscribe!" alt="Arshdeep Soni"><img src="images/social/instagram.png" /></a>
<a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.facebook.com/MagicArsh" title="Arshdeep Soni on Facebook" alt="Facebook"><img src="images/social/fb.png" /></a>
                <a class="socialIcons" href="http://twitter.com/ArshSoni" title="Follow Arshdeep on Twitter" alt="Twitter"><img src="images/social/twitter.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
                body {
                    background-color: black;
                }

                .icons {
                    text-align: center;
                    position:absolute;
                    bottom:0px;
                    left:0;
                    width: 100%;
                    border:2px solid red;
                }    
                .main {
                    width: 700px; 
                    margin: 0 auto; 
                    text-align: left; 
                }

                #middle {
                    height:100px;
                }


            </style>
```

**JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/dzx9v25b/**

Answer (score 0):

should try this..

```
.sI{
 position: relative;
}
.icons{
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Does not indicate how and why and offer's no education.

Answer (score 0):

Just change position:absolute to **position:relative** for your .icons(icons class) in CSS

[JSFiddle : Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o2vushea/)

**CSS** (EDITED)

```
     body
     {
     background-color: black;
     margin: 0; /* ADDED */
     }
     .main {
     width: 700px; 
     height: auto; /* ADDED */
     overflow: auto; /* ADDED */
     margin: 0 auto; 
     text-align: left; 
     }

     #pg {
     position: relative;
     display: block; /* ADDED */
     height: auto; /* REPLACED by 585px */
     background: #000;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
     margin-top: 50px;
 }
```

Comment: Only problem is that when the gallery height is changed, it then overlaps the Icons div, and I want that if the gallery is resized, the icons div just moves down to avoid overlapping

Comment: See this is updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o2vushea/1/), where i created some more dummy images(repeated your 1st image couple of times), to check but its not overlapping now.

Comment: added my JSFiddle Code above with the CSS for the ImageGallery

Comment: Commented the specs where i added or replaced in your CSS

Comment: the first part of my answer is about using reltive and the second part if he wanted it inside the viewport because he does say he wants it at the bottom of the screen...... thats quite rude @divy

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "position:absolute;" in the class .icons should solve your problem. This would generally make your position element static by default. This [link](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) has a good discussion of the different ways of positioning your elements through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**To keep icons at bottom of the page**

Remove `height: 585px;` from `#pg` and give it `overflow:auto;`

you need `overflow:auto;` for containers with floated elements in order to keep there ability to stretch to fit the content as `float` removes elements from the regular flow.

also giving your `#pg` container a height tricks the rest of the document into thinking it ends sooner which was causing your overlap.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzx9v25b/)

```css
 body {
   background-color: black;
 }
 .icons {
   text-align: center;
   bottom: 0px;
   position: relative;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .main {
   width: 700px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: left;
 }
 #pg {
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
   background: #000;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-top: 50px;
 }
 #pg li {
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
   width: 175px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   z-index: 2;
   opacity: .6;
 }
 #pg li.active {
   opacity: 1;
   border-color: white;
 }
 #pg li.selected {
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 99;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
 }
 #pg li img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
 }
 #pg li p {
   color: white;
   margin: 10px 0;
   font-size: 12px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Images</title>
<!--[if IE]>
    <link href="jphotogrid.ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="example/jphotogrid.js"></script>
<script src="example/jflickrfeed.js"></script>
<script src="example/setup.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="header"></div> <span class="menu-Trigger" align="center">&#9776; Menu</span>

  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>VIDEOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="current"><a href="Images.html">IMAGES</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>EVENTS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>TESTIMONIALS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">ENQUIRIES</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <ul id="pg">
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3647/3435384001_9ed9864bb4.jpg" alt="DSC_0660">
        <p>DSC_0660</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3311/3436188742_caaa28c689.jpg" alt="DSC_0698">
        <p>DSC_0698</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3371/3436188466_418a0d8a06.jpg" alt="DSC_0668">
        <p>DSC_0668</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3397/3436188128_5e503cefcd.jpg" alt="DSC_0704">
        <p>DSC_0704</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3300/3436187796_4d228a5bde.jpg" alt="DSC_0699">
        <p>DSC_0699</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3386/3435382439_68b5e3742b.jpg" alt="DSC_0602">
        <p>DSC_0602</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3657/3436187288_e84058f54b.jpg" alt="DSC_0603">
        <p>DSC_0603</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3405/3436187010_c731dea9a3.jpg" alt="DSC_0604">
        <p>DSC_0604</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3403/3435381659_ea615ecf14.jpg" alt="DSC_0607">
        <p>DSC_0607</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3570/3436186474_4e35487600.jpg" alt="DSC_0619">
        <p>DSC_0619</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3339/3434101571_30f6f2bffd.jpg" alt="DSC_0620">
        <p>DSC_0620</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3134/3434099407_32da82e761.jpg" alt="DSC_0590">
        <p>DSC_0590</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3538/3434096369_e2de95b252.jpg" alt="DSC_0562">
        <p>DSC_0562</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3348/3434093487_f5a5b8fdb3.jpg" alt="DSC_0544">
        <p>DSC_0544</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3652/3434091639_dccdc6342a.jpg" alt="DSC_0541">
        <p>DSC_0541</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3537/3434089449_cde6162fa7.jpg" alt="DSC_0532">
        <p>DSC_0532</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3385/3434895530_4bf2857b49.jpg" alt="DSC_0531">
        <p>DSC_0531</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3411/3434069355_7df0d65490.jpg" alt="Dog dogs">
        <p>dogs</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3349/3434870890_3b51171084.jpg" alt="DSC_0693">
        <p>DSC_0693</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3544/3434061033_ba1be12cce.jpg" alt="DSC_0691">
        <p>DSC_0691</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div id="middle"></div>
  </section>
  <div class="sI">
    <div class="icons">
      <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.youtube.com" title="Subscribe on YouTube" alt="Arshdeep on YouTube">
        <img src="images/social/youtube.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.instagram.com/ArshSoni" title="Subscribe!" alt="Arshdeep Soni">
        <img src="images/social/instagram.png" />
      </a>

      <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.facebook.com/MagicArsh" title="Arshdeep Soni on Facebook" alt="Facebook">
        <img src="images/social/fb.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="socialIcons" href="http://twitter.com/ArshSoni" title="Follow Arshdeep on Twitter" alt="Twitter">
        <img src="images/social/twitter.png" />
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

if you where looking to keep them in view at all times then vv

---

**To Keep Icons at bottom of view-port**

I have updated your [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dzx9v25b/3/).

your icons need `position:fixed;` to stay at the bottom view-port you also needed a higher `z-index` to keep them above your images.

hope it helps!

```css
 body {
   background-color: black;
 }
 .icons {
   text-align: center;
   bottom: 0px;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 9999999
 }
 .main {
   width: 700px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: left;
 }
 #pg {
   position: relative;
   height: 585px;
   background: #000;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-top: 50px;
 }
 #pg li {
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
   width: 175px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   z-index: 2;
   opacity: .6;
 }
 #pg li.active {
   opacity: 1;
   border-color: white;
 }
 #pg li.selected {
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 99;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
 }
 #pg li img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
 }
 #pg li p {
   color: white;
   margin: 10px 0;
   font-size: 12px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Images</title>
<!--[if IE]>
    <link href="jphotogrid.ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="example/jphotogrid.js"></script>
<script src="example/jflickrfeed.js"></script>
<script src="example/setup.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="header"></div> <span class="menu-Trigger" align="center">&#9776; Menu</span>

  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>VIDEOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="current"><a href="Images.html">IMAGES</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>EVENTS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>TESTIMONIALS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">ENQUIRIES</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <ul id="pg">
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3647/3435384001_9ed9864bb4.jpg" alt="DSC_0660">
        <p>DSC_0660</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3311/3436188742_caaa28c689.jpg" alt="DSC_0698">
        <p>DSC_0698</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3371/3436188466_418a0d8a06.jpg" alt="DSC_0668">
        <p>DSC_0668</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3397/3436188128_5e503cefcd.jpg" alt="DSC_0704">
        <p>DSC_0704</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3300/3436187796_4d228a5bde.jpg" alt="DSC_0699">
        <p>DSC_0699</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3386/3435382439_68b5e3742b.jpg" alt="DSC_0602">
        <p>DSC_0602</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3657/3436187288_e84058f54b.jpg" alt="DSC_0603">
        <p>DSC_0603</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3405/3436187010_c731dea9a3.jpg" alt="DSC_0604">
        <p>DSC_0604</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3403/3435381659_ea615ecf14.jpg" alt="DSC_0607">
        <p>DSC_0607</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3570/3436186474_4e35487600.jpg" alt="DSC_0619">
        <p>DSC_0619</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3339/3434101571_30f6f2bffd.jpg" alt="DSC_0620">
        <p>DSC_0620</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3134/3434099407_32da82e761.jpg" alt="DSC_0590">
        <p>DSC_0590</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3538/3434096369_e2de95b252.jpg" alt="DSC_0562">
        <p>DSC_0562</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3348/3434093487_f5a5b8fdb3.jpg" alt="DSC_0544">
        <p>DSC_0544</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3652/3434091639_dccdc6342a.jpg" alt="DSC_0541">
        <p>DSC_0541</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3537/3434089449_cde6162fa7.jpg" alt="DSC_0532">
        <p>DSC_0532</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3385/3434895530_4bf2857b49.jpg" alt="DSC_0531">
        <p>DSC_0531</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3411/3434069355_7df0d65490.jpg" alt="Dog dogs">
        <p>dogs</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3349/3434870890_3b51171084.jpg" alt="DSC_0693">
        <p>DSC_0693</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3544/3434061033_ba1be12cce.jpg" alt="DSC_0691">
        <p>DSC_0691</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div id="middle"></div>
  </section>
  <div class="sI">
    <div class="icons">
      <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.youtube.com" title="Subscribe on YouTube" alt="Arshdeep on YouTube">
        <img src="images/social/youtube.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.instagram.com/ArshSoni" title="Subscribe!" alt="Arshdeep Soni">
        <img src="images/social/instagram.png" />
      </a>

      <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.facebook.com/MagicArsh" title="Arshdeep Soni on Facebook" alt="Facebook">
        <img src="images/social/fb.png" />
      </a>
      <a class="socialIcons" href="http://twitter.com/ArshSoni" title="Follow Arshdeep on Twitter" alt="Twitter">
        <img src="images/social/twitter.png" />
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Overflow auto is hiding the entire image gallery

Comment: Remove height: 585px; from #pg

Comment: I have updated your fiddle for you so you can see it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one it might be helpfull for you

```
 .icons {
                    text-align: center;
                    position:absolute;
                    bottom:0px;
                    left:0;
                    width: 100%;
                    border:2px solid red;
                }
```

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing here. Otherwise, you're just writing markup for him and no one is learning from that.